# Mat.get equivalent for C++?

Tags: c++, opencv, native

I'm trying to duplicate an example for line detection from java to native code.

My Java code is as follows

```
int[] linesArray = new int[lines.cols() * lines.rows() * lines.channels()];
lines.get(0,0,linesArray); //the function in question. Reads Mat data into the lines array

for (int i=0; i < linesArray.length; i = i + 4)
{
    //loop through the data and do stuff       
}
```

but in C++ native code, there is no `Mat::get()` function. How can I read the data from my `lines` Mat into my `linesArray`

so far I have this for C++, mostly the same

```
int linesArray[lines.cols * lines.rows * lines.channels()];
lines.get(0,0,linesArray); //get is not a member of cv::Mat
```

Comment: unless `lines.cols`, `lines.rows`, and `lines.channels()` are all `constexpr` (which I suspect is not the case), you cannot use them for stack allocated arrays. You will need to heap allocate with either `new` or something like `std::vector`

Comment: [cv::Mat::data](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a4d33bed1c850265370d2af0ff02e1564) if you really need to get at the underlying array. For iteration there are [iterators](http://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a33ee3bc402827f587a5ad64b568d6986).

Comment: And just out of curiosity, what's in the body of that loop?

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/master/d9/db0/tutorial_hough_lines.html

Comment: tldr: just a line drawing function, but we resize our image to increase performance, so we need to also scale the points as well